# use twitter api to tweet html element's content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a random quote generator then use a tweet button to tweet the current quote (the content of the

element) but I can only get the twitter api to tweet the url, I have researched and read but am completely stuck any help would be wonderful!
Here is HTML with twitter button

```
<body>
<h1>J.R.R. Tolkien Quote Machine!</h1>

<div id ="stuff">
<img id="image" src="http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/images_zpsukywovht.jpg">
<h2 id = "quotetext">Press the button to discover the first quote.</h2>

<button id = "quotebutton" onclick = "randomQuote()">Get a new quote...      </button>

</div>
<!--tweet the url-->
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


</body>
```

here is my javascript...

```
var myQuotes = [
  "'Faithless is he that says farewell when the road darkens.'",
  "'All we have to decide is what to do with the time that is given us.'",
  "'If more of us valued food and cheer and song above hoarded gold, it would be a merrier world.'",
  "'Never laugh at live dragons.'",
  "'There is some good in this world, and it's worth fighting for.'",
  "'Faithless is he that says farewell when the road darkens.'",
  "'The world is indeed full of peril, and in it there are many dark places; but still there is much that is fair, and though in all lands love is now mingled with grief, it grows perhaps the greater.'",
  "'Many that live deserve death. And some that die deserve life. Can you give it to them? Then do not be too eager to deal out death in judgement.'",
  "'Not all those who wander are lost.'",
  "'I will not say: do not weep; for not all tears are an evil.'",
  "'Little by little, one travels far'",
  "'Courage is found in unlikely places.'",
  "'It's the job that's never started as takes longest to finish.'",
  "'There is nothing like looking, if you want to find something. You certainly usually find something, if you look, but it is not always quite the something you were after.'",
  "'The wide world is all about you: you can fence yourselves in, but you cannot forever fence it out.'",
  "'It may be the part of a friend to rebuke a friend's folly.'",
]
var myImages = [
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/p0232nkj_zpsevgnb5vx.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/lord-of-the-rings-quiz-orig_zpsse5k5mrg.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/12d212546fbb50f1f278db8d3c893b05_zpsqzlpz91p.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/imgres1_zpsdsmi4elj.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/samwise-gamgee_zpsrhuv2u33.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/p0232nkj_zpsevgnb5vx.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/images2_zpsgyxpexod.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/gollum_zpsy583lrzv.png",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/images_zpsonmjtyty.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/imagesq_zpsfgguq2ha.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/imgres_zpsesxdolbh.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/images_zps9qwoibjr.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/imgresw_zpseizew5r4.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/The-Hobbit-An-Unexpected-Journey-2012-1_zpsjxz1lw9i.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/middleearthlargelargerstill_zpscp5xil1m.jpg",
  "http://i1376.photobucket.com/albums/ah30/joecarlowittosi/lord_of_the_rings-_the_fellowship_of_the_ring_wallpaper_15_1024_zpssafzudw9.jpg"
]

function randomQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myQuotes.length));
  document.getElementById("quotetext").innerHTML = myQuotes[randomNumber];
  document.getElementById("image").src = myImages[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at all into [how to use the tweet button](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button)?

Comment: sure i have tried a lot of different things, searched the twitter api site but can't find a way to make the content of my <p> element into a tweet

Comment: sorry i mean <h2> element

Comment: I also tried this(which didn't solve it!)$("#quotetext").text(data.quotetext);
  var quot = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + data.quotetext;
  
  $(".twitter-share-button").attr("href", quot);